# Different sets of language icons per theme

Tags: 7, blocks, i18n-l10n

I'm using [Language Icons](http://drupal.org/project/languageicons) and [Language Switcher](http://drupal.org/project/language_switcher) modules. The flag icons are added to the language switcher block, but the icons are stored in **sites/all/modules/languageicons/flags**. They are of fixed height of 12 pixels by default and they are used by every theme.

I want to use different sets of flag icons with different dimensions per theme, for example, Theme 1 will use the default icons of 12x12 pixels, but Theme 2 will use the icons of 19x19 pixels. I will have my custom flag icons in my custom module or in my custom themes.

I would do this by using [hook_block_view_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) to override the block output per theme, but I'm looking for a better and right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my question, I could not do this by using `hook_block_view_alter()` because I can only have the renderable HTML of the block content in that hook.

I found a theme function `theme_languageicons_icon`, which renders the icons, in the file **sites/all/modules/ languageicons/languageicons.module**. I copied the theme function into my custom module and implemented [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6) to override it.
Then, I updated the function as my need and flushed caches. It gave me exactly what I needed.

```
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry){
    if( isset($theme_registry['languageicons_icon']) ){
        $theme_registry['languageicons_icon']['function'] = 'theme_mymodule_languageicons_icon';
    }
}

function theme_mymodule_languageicons_icon($variables) {
  global $theme;
  $language = $variables['language'];
  $title    = $variables['title'];
  # define icons path for various themes
  $default_path = variable_get('languageicons_path', drupal_get_path('module', 'languageicons') . '/flags/*.png');
  $path_by_theme = array(
    'theme1' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme1') . '/flags/*.png'
    'theme2' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme2') . '/flags/*.png'
  );
  $path = (isset($path_by_theme[$theme]) && file_exists($path_by_theme[$theme])) ? $path_by_theme[$theme] : $default_path;
  # define dimension for various themes
  $default_size = check_plain(variable_get('languageicons_size', '16x12'));
  $size_by_theme = array(
    'theme1' => '19x19',
    'theme2' => '25x24',
  );
  $size = (isset($size_by_theme[$theme])) ? $size_by_theme[$theme] : $default_size;

  if ($path) {
    $title = $title ? $title : $language->native;
    // Build up $image for theme_image() consumption.
    $image = array(
      'path' => str_replace('*', $language->language, check_plain($path)),
      'alt' => $title,
      'title' => $title,
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => 'language-icon',
      ),
    );
    if ($size) {
      list($width, $height) = explode('x', $size);
      $image += array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height);
    }
    return theme('image', $image);
  }
}
```

If you have a better solution, it is welcome.

Comment: nice one, thanks (I just need to change the flag size, but this has it all)